# Trying to get property of non-object - Laravel-5.5 inserting into db

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have used the following code to insert several times into the DB but randomly it gives me the error exception for trying to get property of non-object.
Also, sometimes it fails to recognise the $test->data[] 
(by the error 
[ErrorException]  Undefined property: stdClass::$data)
I understand most responses to this questions have suggested to use $test['data'] but as you can see my response body has several arrays within an array and I need to access very specific values.

```
 for($j=1;$j<50;$j++)
   {    
        sleep(30);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "specified URL");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $test=json_decode($response,true); 

        $size=count($test['data']);

        for($i=0;$i<$size;$i++)
        { 

        $start_date=date_create($test->data[$i]->opportunity->earliest_start_date);
        $end_date=date_create($test->data[$i]->opportunity->latest_end_date);
        $app_close_date=date_create($test->data[$i]->opportunity->applications_close_date);
        $date_approved=date_create($test->data[$i]->date_approved);
        $date_realized=date_create($test->data[$i]->date_realized);
        $experience_start_date=date_create($test->data[$i]->experience_start_date);
        $experience_end_date=date_create($test->data[$i]->experience_end_date);
        $signup_date=date_create($test->data[$i]->created_at);

        DB::insert('insert ignore into Opportunity (opportunity_id,opportunity_location,office_id,programme_name,title,earliest_start_date,latest_end_date,applications_close_date) values (?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?, ?)', [$test->data[$i]->opportunity->id,$test->data[$i]->opportunity->location, $test->data[$i]->opportunity->office->id, $test->data[$i]->opportunity->programmes->short_name,$test->data[$i]->opportunity->title,date_format($start_date,"Y-m-d H:i:s"),date_format($end_date,"Y-m-d H:i:s"),date_format($app_close_date,"Y-m-d H:i:s")]);
        DB::insert('insert ignore into Home_LC (id, country, name) values (?, ?, ?)', [$test->data[$i]->person->home_lc->id,$test->data[$i]->person->home_lc->country,$test->data[$i]->person->home_lc->name]);
        DB::insert('insert ignore into Applications (app_id,ep_id,opportunity_id,date_approved,date_realized,experience_start_date,experience_end_date) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', [$test->data[$i]->id,$test->data[$i]->person->id,$test->data[$i]->opportunity->id,date_format($date_approved,"Y-m-d H:i:s"),date_format($date_realized,"Y-m-d H:i:s"),date_format($experience_start_date,"Y-m-d H:i:s"),date_format($experience_end_date,"Y-m-d H:i:s")]);
        DB::insert('insert ignore into ep_users (ep_id,first_name,last_name,email,home_lc_id,signup_date,dob,status) values (?, ?,?, ?,?, ?,?, ?)', [$test->data[$i]->person->id,$test->data[$i]->person->first_name,$test->data[$i]->person->last_name,$test->data[$i]->person->email,$test->data[$i]->person->home_lc->id,date_format($signup_date,"Y-m-d H:i:s"),$test->data[$i]->person->dob,$test->data[$i]->status]);


        }

    }
```

Given above is the code which fetches a json file and then using json_decode it gives an answer like this:

```
array:3
 [
  "paging" => array:3 
[
    "total_items" => 216822
    "current_page" => 1
    "total_pages" => 1085
  ]
  "data" => array:200 [
    0 => array:19 [
      "id" => 3719730
      "url" => ""
      "status" => "open"
      "current_status" => "open"
      "an_signed_at" => null
      "nps_grade" => null
      "date_realized" => null
      "date_approved" => null
      "custom_status" => null
      "experience_start_date" => null
      "experience_end_date" => null
      "favourite" => null
      "person" => array:23 [ …23]
      "opportunity" => array:15 [ …15]
      "standards" => []
      "scheduled_interview" => null
      "permissions" => array:26 [ …26]
      "created_at" => "2017-12-14T10:27:06Z"
      "updated_at" => "2017-12-14T10:27:06Z"
    ]
....
    198 => array:19 [ …19]
    199 => array:19 [ …19]
  ]
  "facets" => null
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed `$test=json_decode($response,true);` to `$test=json_decode($response);`
and 
`$size=count($test['data'])` to `$size=count($test->data)`

When json_decode($variable, **true**) is used, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `$test` is  array and not object.

Replace all occurrences of:

```
$test->data
```

into

```
$test['data']
```

Comment: Yes, but like I mentioned earlier, It doesn't help with a statement such as `$test->data[$i]->opportunity->earliest_start_date` to write `$test['data']['opportunity']['earliest_start_date']`